# image_transport republish One Time Use

Tags: ros, rospy, image-transport, compressed-image-transport, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I have several rosbags, 8 seconds long each, which only contain compressed depth images. Since rospy does not support compressedDepth (as far as I know) I am using

```
rosrun image_transport republish
```

to go from compressedDepth to raw. But I noticed that only the first rosbag's image gets republished, but not any rosbag after that, unless I re-run the image transport code above after each rosbag finishes playing...**kind of a lame behavior in my opinion**. Is there an option to tell **republish** to continue republishing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249929/image_transport-republish-one-time-use/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind. I added image_transport to my lunch file instead of doing rosrun, and now it works...still weird that it does not continuously tries to resubscribe after the original publishers stops publishing, though.

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0